# Continually output resource monitor information to files in linux

Tags: linux-kernel, rhel

So I am attempting to sample the output of the resource monitor in order to get an idea of how specific test cases affect the machine over time, but I have not been able to find a way to continually output information from the resource monitor (using top command on RHEL) into a new file or existing log file (or is there a log file that exists already for this?). I am attempting to data mine the resource monitor to find the optimal load balancing for specific instances on this host.

I do not want to cause too much variation in the resources by doing so, but i am aware that there will be some error in the resources caused by creating new files. (I will normalize accordingly)

Comment: You can't pipe the `top` output to a file? `top -d 10|tee file.txt`?

Comment: It seems to create some wild output. but i suppose i can sift through it. Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer which should give you a much saner output I hope for your use and avoid you _sifting_ through the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-b` (batch) option for `top` to make its output more amenable to being output to a file.

```
user:~$ top -n 1 -b> dump.txt
user:~$ top -n 1 > dump_nob.txt
user:~$ file dump.txt
dump.txt: ASCII text
user:~$ file dump_nob.txt
dump_nob.txt: ASCII text, with very long lines, with escape sequences
```

That `dump_nob.txt` is probably not what you want. Of course, the other options for `top` like `-d <interval>` continue to be available.

```
top -n 5 -d 2 -b> dump1.txt
```